# Create async stored procedure call in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, async-await

I have imported a stored procedure into my EF6 data model. Now I want to call that asynchronously, but it seems like EF doesn't create an `Async` version of the SP. Do I miss something here?

```
db.CallMyProcedure(param);
// vs
await db.CallMyProcedureAsync(param);
```

Comment: No. It's just that database-first (EDMX) is obsolete technology from a time that async-await didn't exist yet and the option was never added later.

Comment: I've never tried it, but await Task.Run(() => db.CallMyProcedure(param)); is not enough for your goal ?

Comment: @Miite: `await Task.Run` will call the same synchronous `CallMyProcedure` on a background thread which is not the same thing as calling an asynchronous method. You may use it to offload blocking work from the calling thread though.

Comment: @GertArnold It's the technology that is used in my company right now, so I don't really have a choice. Our current workflow is to create a Visual Studio database project first, lay down all the tables, views and stored procedures, publish it to our DB server and then create a model from it.

Comment: @mm8 The method, that uses this SPC, is just a SignalR wrapper. I don't think that putting a `Task.Run` around it would make it any better.

Comment: @AndréReichelt: That's exactly my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of solved the problem by adding my own methods to the (luckily) `partial` model class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My.Softwares.Namespace.Model {
    public partial class DatabaseEntities {
        public virtual Task<int> CancelCurrentForkliftDeliveryAsync(int? iD_Carrier) {
            return Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
                "exec dbo.CancelCurrentForkliftDelivery @ID_Carrier",
                new SqlParameter("@ID_Carrier", iD_Carrier)
            );
        }
    }
}
```